# SQL | JOIN USING vs JOIN ON

Tags: sql, join

Well, this probably is just a *"matter of style"* question but I really would like to learn a little more about the difference between `JOIN t ON <equal condition>` and `JOIN t USING(<list of columns>)`.

Of course I'm assuming the two tables have the same columns, with the same name and the same data-types. In such case:

- is there any *real* difference between the two syntaxes?
- is the `USING` clause supported in all (or at least the most important) dbms *s*?

I already read about `NATURAL JOIN` on [w3resource.com](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/natural-join.php) and the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510952/when-to-use-sql-natural-join-instead-of-join-on) about `NATURAL JOIN` vs `ON` clause but they don't seem to answer the previous two questions...
Moreover, neither the w3resource.com [`EQUI JOIN`](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/perform-an-equi-join.php) section nor [`INNER JOIN`](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/perform-an-inner-join.php) section do mention the `USING` "technique".

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support USING.  Also, USING can become confusing where there are multiple tables being joined (I believe, at least in Ingres, it joins the column with identically-named columns in ALL other tables which is not always what you want; ON is more explicit and more flexible in this regard).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For the most part, it is a matter of style (and the fact that not all databases support `using`).  There is one small difference.  If you do:

```
select *
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.col1 = t2.col1
```

Then `col1` appears twice in the result set.  If you do:

```
select *
from t1 join
     t2
     using (col1)
```

Then `col1` appears only once.

One aspect of `using` that I like is that it encourages foreign keys to have the same names as primary keys.  When this is possible (and it is not always possible), I think this is a good design that makes databases easier to use.

There are situations where `using` *could* do unexpected things.  In long chains of `join`s, it doesn't specify where the keys come from.  However, I don't find this to be a problem in well-designed databases.

On the other hand, `natural join`s are an abomination and should never be used.  They do not specify the columns being joined.  They do not even respect foreign key relationships.  Not being clear on the columns being compared is just an invitation for bugs in the code -- bugs that can be really, really hard to find.

Comment: Actually, I believe that in oracle, your second query will crash.

Comment: @DanBracuk . . . I'm not sure why you say that.  I've used `using` with Oracle (http://rextester.com/TQKP83377).  Did I missing something in the answer?